# Integrating node-red in MEAN js existing dashboard

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, node-red

I have a MEAN js application, I already have my dashboard ready.
I want to integrate node-red in it and do a few customization.

Is there a way to do it? All the ways I found were with node-red 's own dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed Node-RED in an existing Express framework app. The documentation on how to do this is [here](http://nodered.org/docs/embedding).

As for the dashboard, you can create your own HTTP API endpoints to feed a dashboard with Node-RED so you should be able to consume it's output in what ever you already have.

Comment: But how can I get the UI on my dashboard?

Comment: If you mean the Node-RED editor then it will be as an iFrame